# Can you flatten files to external table in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a JSON file and when I create an external table in Snowflake and query it the result is each row is a JSON record.

Can I flatten the structure when creating the external table to put each field in a col and row format instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'd define each column in your external table definition.  There are some good parquet examples here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table.html which would be very similar to your JSON use-case.

I would also recommend using an MV over that external table to improve performance.